# Promises fail status

Tags: javascript, express, promise

Promise is either resolve or reject, but I want to have a fail option:

```
users.parse(body)
.then(function (data){
    if(data.status == 'fail') {
        res.fail(data.data);
    } else {
        return users.saveUser(data.data);  
    }     
}).then(function (user) {
    res.success(merchant);
}).catch(function (err) {
    res.error(err);
});
```

So what I basically doing is to have a resolve with status object called 'fail' to indicate it is a fail process, so I send fail message instead of error message.

Am I doing it right, anyway the code above will give me error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, if you need a "third result", you'll have to do it manually. The exception you're experiencing is caused by the fact your `res.success(...)` code is still being executed in the 'fail' scenario, since there was no error to stop it.

A good rule of thumb when doing promises is to implement any condition which should normally interrupt the 'then' flow as a rejection. This would mean that as long as `users.parse` rejects on incorrect input, your code turns into a more natural version, with all errors handled in one place:

```
users.parse(body).then(function(data) {
    return users.saveUser(data.data);
}).then(function (user) {
    res.success(merchant);
}).catch(function(err) {
    if (err == 'fail') {
        res.fail(data.data)
    } else { 
        res.error(err);
    }
});
```

The solutions provided by Bergi work as well if you decide that you want to handle parsing failures on the "success" branch.

Comment: I think I will go with this, putting fail into rejection.

Answer (score 1):

If the user failed, your first callback will return `undefined` and your second `then` callback will still be executed, with a value of `undefined` for `user`. Calling `res.success` after `res.fail` will cause an exception, which will in turn cause the `catch` callback to be executed so it tries to call `res.error` which again throws the error that the headers have already been sent.

You should be able to solve this using

```
users.parse(body).then(function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'fail') {
        res.fail(data.data);
    } else {
        return users.saveUser(data.data).then(function(user) {
            res.success(merchant);
        });
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    res.error(err);
});
```

However, an even cleaner solution would be to use

```
users.parse(body).then(function(data) {
    if (data.status == 'fail') return data;
    else return users.saveUser(data.data);
}).then(function(user) {
    if (data.status == 'fail') 
        res.fail(data.data);
    else
        res.success(merchant);
}, function(err) {
    res.error(err);
});
```

which could gain a bit from using a `Maybe` functor for abstraction.